# PHP namespace Error. Class not found within composer project

Tags: php, namespaces

Can someone please point me in the right direction.  I have downloaded a GIT project Namshi/JOSE which is a JWT signing and verification library.  I have  a directory structure shown below.

[image: directory structure]

All my unit tests (inside the folder *tests* work perfectly, so the *composer.json* and *bootstrap.php* files are okay.  But when I try and add my own test, in the folder *myTests->simpleTest.php* as below what ever I try I can't get the namespace to resolve the class *SimpleJWS*.   The namespace for the library is *Namshi/JOSE*.  My simple test calling code is:

```
    <?php

      use Namshi\JOSE\SimpleJWS;
      //require_once ("../src/Namshi/JOSE/SimpleJWS.php");

      $jws  = new SimpleJWS(array(
       'alg' => 'RS256'
       ));
```

The error text is: `Fatal error: Class 'Namshi\JOSE\SimpleJWS' not found`.  The psr-4 statements are as follows:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "Namshi\\JOSE\\":  "src/Namshi/JOSE/"

    }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Namshi\\JOSE\\Test\\":  "tests/Namshi/JOSE/Test/"

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking about the autoloading is correct, but as you're stating, your test file lives under "myTests"; your autoload-dev simply points to the wrong directory "tests/Namshi/JOSE/Test/" while your file lies in "myTests".

```json
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
         "Namshi\\JOSE\\Test\\": "myTests"
    }
}
```

Please also make sure, your FQCN (fully-qualified class name) of your test class is `Namshi\JOSE\Test\simpleTest`.

```php
<?php

namespace Namshi\JOSE\Test;

class simpleTest {}
```

---

**According to the comments below** you were missing the include of the autoloading in your testsuite.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  But I think there is a misunderstanding.  The entry Namshi\\JOSE\\Test refers to the Unit Tests under the folder **tests**.  The myTests folder is a separate set of tests.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed them up. Do you load the bootstrap in your test?

Comment: I think that might be the crux of it, but I am not sure how to specify that the  bootstrap should be loaded.

Comment: In your screenshot I can see a ``phpunit.xml.dist``: if you're using PHPUnit for your test suite, you can specify a bootstrap in it's [configuration file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

Comment: Michael, looks like you were correct.  The IDE environment that I was working in was not invoking the autoloader for my code.  So I fixed the problem by simply adding _include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';_ at the top of the source file.  The use statement then picked up the libraries as needed.  Gasp!